# How to populate a table (database1) to another table (database2)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to Insert certain column from table A (database2) to be populated into another table B in a different database (database1).

I know how to populate a Table to another table in the same database. 
But I do not know on how to populate in a different database.

I'm using sql server
Thanks.

Comment: It depends on which database management system are you using

Comment: @AutoX . . . (1) tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) show the query that you use when they are in the same database.

Comment: Do you mean updated or inserted rows in table B?

Comment: insert column in Table B

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can use a three part name to refer to a different database:

```
update  b
set     column_in_b = a.column_in_a
from    database2..tableA a
join    database1..tableB b
on      a.id = b.id
```

Comment: I will try this method and see how it goes. Thanks for the share.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a similar request with something like a DBLink in Oracle to see the distant tables as if they where local. However, it is not very performant, dependant of your brand of database, and should be used for small sets of data only.

If you have more important amount of data, and eventually some transformations to do on your data, you may want to use an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool instead.